# Exel VBA Array - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass the value of two cells as a concatenated string to `adata` array, but I am getting a mismatch error. If I only use `aData = rData.Value2` the macro works fine. Not sure how to fix  this.

```
Set ws = x_bs
    sSearchCol = "C"
    sfind = ThisWorkbook.Names("dr_co").RefersToRange(1, 1)
    Set rFindText = ws.Columns(sSearchCol).Find(sfind, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sSearchCol), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
    If rFindText Is Nothing Then GoTo errHandler
    Set rFindBlank = ws.Range(sSearchCol & 1, rFindText).Find(vbNullString, rFindText, xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    Set rData = ws.Range(rFindBlank.Offset(1), rFindText.Offset(-1))

    If rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = rData.Value2 & " - " & rData.Offset(0, 2).Value2
    Else
        aData = rData.Value2 & " - " & rData.Offset(0, 2).Value2
    End If
```

Comment: `aData = rData.Value2 & " - " & rData.Offset(0, 2).Value2` is not valid when `rData` refers to more than one cell (as it will in your else clause).  You'll need to create a loop to populate the array

Comment: is there another workaround apart from looping, perhaps defining another rData for the second value ? Or using Join() function?

Comment: What are you supposed to find, in terms of array size. And what do you want to do with your found data. Perhaps there is a better solution then the one you are trying to implement here.

Comment: @joanna why do you want to avoid a loop?